# Convergence in $(\mathbb{R}^n,d_l^p)$ metrics

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am reading Tao's Real Analysis and Real Analysis 2. In chapter 1.1 of the second book he asks the reader to prove the following Proposition:

> Proposition 1.1.18 (Equivalence of l
> 1, l
> 2, l
> ∞). Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ be a Euclidean
> space, and let $(x^{(k)}
> )^∞
> _{k=m}$ be a sequence of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We write $x(k) =
> (x^{(k)}_1 , x^{(k)}_2 ,...,x^{(k)}_n )$, i.e., for $j = 1, 2,...,n$, $x^{(k)}
> j ∈ \mathbb{R}$ is the jth coordinate of $x(k) ∈ \mathbb{R}^n$. Let x = (x_1,...,x_n) be a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then the
> following four statements are equivalent:
> (a) (x^{(k)})^∞_{k=m} converges to x with respect to the Euclidean metric dl2 .
> (b) (x^{(k)})^∞_{k=m} converges to x with respect to the taxi-cab metric dl1 .
> (c) (x^{(k)})^∞_{k=m} converges to x with respect to the sup norm metric dl∞.

How would one go about this proof?

Comment: What have you done to try to solve the question? Post your efforts and attempts so that users can give you responses according to your understanding of the problem, not just give your the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easy inequalities $$\|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_2  \le \|x\|_1 \le n\|x\|_\infty$$ (for $x$ in ${\mathbb R}^n$)
imply the desired conclusion.

Comment: ||x|| just stands for d(x,0) right?

Comment: Yes. This is the standard notation for a norm.